# MVC how to change webgrid width/height size

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to display datagridview using mvc webgrid.
Since 1 of my columns has to many data inside it cause large width/height which I dont want.
I set the following code using css but no change appears

my view code

```html
div class="row resultP">
    @grid.GetHtml(

  columns: grid.Columns(
  grid.Column("Id"),
  grid.Column("TestId"),
  grid.Column("URL"),
  grid.Column("TestLog", style: "colTestLog"),
  grid.Column("RegistrationType"),
  grid.Column("Country"),
  grid.Column("Time"),
  grid.Column("UserId"),
  grid.Column("CurrencyId"),
  grid.Column("TestResultStatusId"),
  grid.Column("Result"))

)
</div>
```

my css

```css
.colTestLog{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

[image: chrome debug mode]

It looks like td has auto size to content.
Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Solved:
I added div to every td of this column and I changed the div size

```html
<div class="row resultP">
    @grid.GetHtml(

  columns: grid.Columns(
  grid.Column("Id"),
  grid.Column("TestId"),
  grid.Column("URL"),
  grid.Column("TestLog", style: "colTestLog", format:@<div>@item.TestLog</div>),
  grid.Column("RegistrationType"),
  grid.Column("Country"),
  grid.Column("Time"),
  grid.Column("UserId"),
  grid.Column("CurrencyId"),
  grid.Column("TestResultStatusId"),
  grid.Column("Result"))

)
</div>
```

```css
.colTestLog div {
    width: 65px;
    height: 23px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```